# Adding a value to a variable in Django templates

Tags: django

This is a very quick question, which I think may be a limitation in the templates.

I'm adding a value to a variable in a template using the |add:"num" feature, I'm trying to use another variable as the number but it doesn't seem to work.  Should this be possible ?

e.g.

```
{{ pagecontrol.start_page|add:"-pagecontrol.news_per_page" }}
```

Thanks in advance all.

Wayne

Comment: create a template tag and use that for manipulating such cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Django does not provide a built-in template tag/filter to do subtraction. Also, there is no built-in filter for converting a positive integer to negative. You would have to write a template tag for that.**

**Solution 1-** Use a custom template filter:

```
@register.filter
def subtract(value, arg):
    return value - arg
```

Then in your template, you can do something like:

```
{{ pagecontrol.start_page|subtract:pagecontrol.news_per_page }}
```

**Solution 2-** Use [django-mathfilters](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mathfilters) library

You can use Django-mathfilters library to get a subtract filter.

First, load `mathfilters` at the top of your template. Then use `sub` filter in your template like below:

```
{% load mathfilters %}

{{ pagecontrol.start_page|sub:pagecontrol.news_per_page }}
```

**Why your code is not working?**

Django Source code of `add` built-in filter:

```
@register.filter(is_safe=False)
def add(value, arg):
    """Adds the arg to the value."""
    try:
        return int(value) + int(arg)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        try:
            return value + arg
        except Exception:
            return ''
```

When you do `{{ pagecontrol.start_page|add:"-pagecontrol.news_per_page" }}` in your template, `'-pagecontrol.news_per_page'` string is passed as `arg` to the above `add` built-in filter and not its actual value, so exception is raised because of adding integer and string values. `''` is returned as the final value by `add` filter so nothing is displayed.

**NOTE:**

In case of complex variables name, you can use `with` template tag. It will cache a complex variable under a simpler name.

Below is a sample example of using `with` with `add` filter. This will just add the values.

```
{% with my_variable=pagecontrol.news_per_page %}
```

This will store the value of `pagecontrol.news_per_page` in the variable `my_variable`. Then in your template, you can use this variable:

```
{{ pagecontrol.start_page|add:my_variable }}
```

This will add the 2 variables.

```
{% with my_variable=pagecontrol.news_per_page %}

    {{ pagecontrol.start_page|add:my_variable }}

{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Sorry @Rahul-Gupta, that doesnt work.
     {% with newsperpage=-pagecontrol.news_per_page %}
    <li class="previous"><a href="/news/{{ pagecontrol.start_page|add:-newsperpage }}/"><span aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span> Newer News</a></li>
  {% endwith %}
   {% endif %}
   {% if pagecontrol.next_page < pagecontrol.total_records %}
     {% with newsperpage=pagecontrol.news_per_page %}
    <li class="next"><a href="/news/{{ pagecontrol.start_page|add:newsperpage }}/">Older News <span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span></a></li>
  {% endwith %}

Comment: After reading @lorenzo Pena's response, i've passed a negative version of that parameter also.  Thanks for taking the time to post a reply.

Comment: Django does not provide a built-in template tag/filter to do subtraction. We would have to implement it ourselves. Updated the ans with 2 possible solutions you can use.

Answer (score 1):

You basically can't. Apart from what Rahul Gupta said, Django has an explicit design philosohpy to prevent advanced logic in templates (although substracting is not advanced logic at all):

> The template system intentionally doesn’t allow the following:
>
> ```
> - Assignment to variables
> - Advanced logic
> ```
>
> The goal is not to invent a programming language. The goal is to offer
>   just enough programming-esque functionality, such as branching and
>   looping, that is essential for making presentation-related decisions.

You could always create your own filter for substracting based on the Django core `add` filter, also posted by Rahul, or perform any substraction in the view.

Answer (score -2):

You need something like:

```
{{ pagecontrol.start_page|sub:pagecontrol.new_per_page }}
```